# Google sheets: How to get the row number of a cell in a different sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, row, vlookup

Basically, in the expression I'm writing, it searches for a certain text in an interval in a different sheet using `VLOOKUP`, and if it finds it, it must get the number of the row the text is. I can't find a simple way of doing the second step, since as far as I know, `VLOOKUP` can only return the searched value, and `ROW` can only be used to return the line number of the current sheet.

Comment: `MATCH` on the entire column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=MATCH(A1; Sheet1!A:A; 0)
```

where A1 is somewhere in Sheet1 A column

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF(Sheet2!A:A=A2,ROW(Sheet2!A:A),"")," Where Col1 is not null",0))
```

[image]